# How to solve AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG' in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, background, subtraction

When this code is executed I get the result, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG'. An OpenCV tutorial for [Background Subtraction](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html) used this object so I would assume it worked for them.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('camera17.h264')

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

while(1):
ret, frame = cap.read()

fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)


cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I knew it's a bit late to answer this question though, I met the same one and roughly solved it by merely searching all functions in moudle cv2. And I only  found function 'createBackgroundSubtracorMOG2' exists. Hope this helps the others confront the same situation.

Comment: btw, i met another issue shows "the data should normally be NULL!..." whiling using this function call, and workaround it by appending one line "cv2.ocl.setOpenCL(False)", problem fix.  Dont know why....

Answer (score 1):

I was using an out-dated method. `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()` is the appropriate one.